# Getting error during npm run build on server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, npm-install

I have tried to deploy my application on the hosting server and I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_app.js
Error: failed to process The global thread pool has not been initialized.: ThreadPoolBuildError { kind: IOError(Os { code: 11, kind: WouldBlock, message: "Resource temporarily unavailable" }) }

./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js
Error: failed to process The global thread pool has not been initialized.: ThreadPoolBuildError { kind: GlobalPoolAlreadyInitialized }

./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_error.js
Error: failed to process The global thread pool has not been initialized.: ThreadPoolBuildError { kind: GlobalPoolAlreadyInitialized }

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_error.js

./app/[...uri]/loading.js
Error: failed to process The global thread pool has not been initialized.: ThreadPoolBuildError { kind: GlobalPoolAlreadyInitialized }

Import trace for requested module:
./app/[...uri]/loading.js

./app/[...uri]/page.js
Error: failed to process The global thread pool has not been initialized.: ThreadPoolBuildError { kind: GlobalPoolAlreadyInitialized }

Import trace for requested module:
./app/[...uri]/page.js
```

On my local machine, everything works fine. I've tried to reinstall `node_modules` and deleting `package-lock.json`. What do I have to change or edit?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Docker? I think it's because the hosting server uses a different operating system.

Install Docker, then try
`docker build -t your-image-name .`.
After that, you can run your build:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -d your-image-name
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately still getting the same message.

Comment: did you try delete node_modules and then install them again?
sometimes this is issue and i dont get it why i occures

Comment: Yes, I've tried to change webpacks version also.